# Finding Prime numbers given Germain quadratic equation

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

I have a large number $n$ (1250 decimal digits), which is a product of 2 prime numbers, which happen to be Germain prime numbers. I have to find the two prime numbers, have been given a quadratic equation $2x^2+x-n = 0$.

*To apply the quadratic formula, you will need to find the square root of the discriminant D as an exact integer.*

How do I find the discriminant without knowing the Phi value, which I cannot calculate since n is too large, cannot use Factorization either.

Any help would be much appreciated. Stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: You have $n$ , so you can solve the quadratic equation

Comment: Search for online quadratic equation solvers for large $n$. If there are non, then search for code for programming one

Comment: What is the relevance of the quadratic equation in $n$? Is it true that $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are Germain primes and both are roots of that equation? That would be pretty trivial.

Comment: If you give us the $n$ I could give the determinant easily: it's just the square root of $8n + 1$, and exact integer roots are easy to find. A small C program suffices with some libgmp help.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh my, I thought the n is not known.

Comment: @kelalaka $n$ is the modulus of RSA so must be known.

Answer (score 0):

As Henno says in the comments, square roots that happen to be exact integers are easy to find. The reason is this: not-so-bad approximations of square roots are easy to find and once you have a non-so-bad approximation, you can just test which of the most nearby integers is the squareroot by trial and error (i.e. squaring them).

There are various algorithms for approximating square roots. I like the following one (allegedly invented by the ancient Babylonians) because it is easy to understand why it works:

1) Guess a first approximation $a_1$. It need not be a good guess, even something that is obviously wrong like $a_1 = 54$ might do.

2) Compute a second approximation $b_1$ by $b_1 = D/a_1$, where $D$ is the number you want to take the square root of. (So in your case $D = 8n + 1$)

If $a_1$ was too small (that is $a_1 < \sqrt{D}$), then $b_1$ is too big and if $a_1$ was too big then $b_1$ is to small. This suggest a way to find a second approximation $a_2$ that is a better approximation of $\sqrt{D}$ than $a_1$ was:

3) Compute $a_2 = \frac{a_1 + b_1}{2}$

4) Compute $b_2 = D/a_2$

Just as we like to believe that $a_2$ is closer to $\sqrt{D}$ than $a_1$ was, we believe that $b_2$ is closer to $\sqrt{D}$ than $b_1$ was. And again, if $a_2$ was an underestimation of $\sqrt{D}$ then $b_2$ is an overestimation and vice versa, so we can get an even better approximation by computing:

5) $a_3 = \frac{a_2 + b_2}{2}$

6) $b_3 = D/a_3$

7) $a_4 = \frac{a_3 + b_3}{2}$

etc etc.

You will be surprised how quickly these approximations of $\sqrt{D}$ get better, as can be seen for instance from the shrinking distance between $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Of course once you arrive at a point that there is only a single integer between $a_i$ and $b_i$ you know that this integer must be your answer (unless you made computing error somewhere).